# Interactive Emacs Lisp function to swap two words with each other

Tags: emacs, elisp, swap

My first foray into the quirky world of emacs lisp is a function which takes two strings and swaps them with eachother:

```
(defun swap-strings (a b)
  "Replace all occurances of a with b and vice versa"
  (interactive "*sFirst Swap Word: \nsSecond Swap Word: ")
  (save-excursion
    (while (re-search-forward (concat a "\\|" b) nil t)
      (if (equal (match-string 0) a)
      (replace-match b)
    (replace-match a)))))
```

This works - but I'm stuck on the following:

- how to prompt the user for confirmation before each replacement? (I can't get `perform-replace` to work)
- how to escape the strings `a` and `b` so they don't get interpreted as regexes if they contain any regex characters?

Edit: The final copy-pastable code I've been using for some time is:

```
(defun swap-words (a b)
  "Replace all occurances of a with b and vice versa"
  (interactive "*sFirst Swap Word: \nsSecond Swap Word: ")
  (save-excursion
    (while (re-search-forward (concat (regexp-quote a) "\\|" (regexp-quote b)))
      (if (y-or-n-p "Swap?") 
      (if (equal (match-string 0) a)
          (replace-match (regexp-quote b))
        (replace-match (regexp-quote a))))
      )))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't highlight upcoming matches on the page like I-search does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `y-or-n-p` for the first: `(when (y-or-n-p "Swap?") do stuff`

And `regexp-quote` for the second: `(regexp-quote your-string)`

Answer (score 1):

`regexp-quote` is [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768243/interactive-emacs-lisp-function-to-swap-two-words-with-eachother/768349#768349).

As for the confirmation, if you want to ask the user before *each* replacement, you may choose `query-replace-regexp` that does exactly what you want.

(And you can still deal with Emacs's builtin [transponse functions](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Transpose).)